# How do I limit users to just the DBSQL lens of Databricks? I don't want them to have access to SQL endpoints or DE & ML lenses

Tags: databricks, acl, databricks-sql, dbsql

Here are the current options. I want to give the BI team only access to the S: SQL

[image: Databricks lenses]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely removing the other options is currently not available. However, you can lock them as shown in the picture.

1. Remove databricks-sql-access entitlement from default users group.
2. Create a new group called 'sql-users-only' and give them only this entitlement. (so they won't see workspace and they can't spin up endpoints)

[image: what users see]

Resources:
Databricks provide a lot of control using ACLs. [Access control overview](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/security/access-control/index.html)
You can restrict the dashboard viewing options as well. [Dashboard permissions](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/security/access-control/dashboard-acl.html#dashboard-permissions)